# Error bottomnav allows you to navigate through the views but stops working on one of them

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, bottomnavigationview

Hi i have made a bottom navigationview in my app and from the start everything was working but then suddenly it stopped. When i went into settings tabe it just stops working with the navigation i cant eaven click it anymore why could this be? i have not done much except adding a listview to the fragment which it stops working in???? can it have something with that to do. i understand that it really has not much to do with bottomnavview more with navgraph i think so i will post that to. I took a look on the problem again it is clearly the listview that removes the function to navigate. I wonder what is it that does this?

bottom_menu file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/mainMenuFragment"
          android:title="Menu"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_format_list_bulleted_24"
        />
    <item android:id="@+id/paperCountFragment"
          android:title="Calculation"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_calculate" />

    <item android:id="@+id/placeholder"
          android:title=""/>

    <item android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
          android:title="Profile"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
          android:title="Settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"/>

</menu>
```

activity main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomApp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabCradleMargin="8dp"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="8dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="#9FCBA0">


        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"/>

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomApp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_round_add_24"/>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/NavHost"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navgraph" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Navgraph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_navgraph"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainMenuFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/registerFragment"
        android:name="com.jens.svensson.paper_seller.UI.authentication.RegisterFragment"
        android:label="fragment_login"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_registerFragment_to_mainMenuFragment"
            app:destination="@id/mainMenuFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainMenuFragment"
        android:name="com.jens.svensson.paper_seller.UI.main.MainMenuFragment"
        android:label="fragment_main_menu"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_menu" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainMenuFragment_to_paperCountFragment"
            app:destination="@id/paperCountFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainMenuFragment_to_profileFragment"
            app:destination="@id/profileFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainMenuFragment_to_settingsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/settingsFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainMenuFragment_to_loginFragment"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:name="com.jens.svensson.paper_seller.UI.main.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_settings"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_settingsFragment_to_mainMenuFragment"
            app:destination="@id/mainMenuFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_settingsFragment_to_paperCountFragment"
            app:destination="@id/paperCountFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_settingsFragment_to_profileFragment"
            app:destination="@id/profileFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:name="com.jens.svensson.paper_seller.UI.main.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="fragment_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_profileFragment_to_mainMenuFragment"
            app:destination="@id/mainMenuFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_profileFragment_to_paperCountFragment"
            app:destination="@id/paperCountFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_profileFragment_to_settingsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/settingsFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/paperCountFragment"
        android:name="com.jens.svensson.paper_seller.UI.main.PaperCountFragment"
        android:label="fragment_paper_count"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_paper_count" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_paperCountFragment_to_mainMenuFragment"
            app:destination="@id/mainMenuFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_paperCountFragment_to_profileFragment"
            app:destination="@id/profileFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_paperCountFragment_to_settingsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/settingsFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.jens.svensson.paper_seller.UI.authentication.LoginFragment"
        android:label="LoginFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_mainMenuFragment"
            app:destination="@id/mainMenuFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_registerFragment"
            app:destination="@id/registerFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Main Activity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val authViewModel : AuthViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var bottomAppBar : BottomAppBar
    private lateinit var fab : FloatingActionButton

    private lateinit var _binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val binding get() = _binding!!



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        _binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.NavHost) as NavHostFragment


         bottomNavigationView = binding.bottomNav
         bottomAppBar = binding.bottomApp

         fab = binding.fab
         navController = navHostFragment.navController




        bottomNavigationView.background = null
        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
        bottomNavigationView.menu.getItem(2).isEnabled = false


        setupNav()

        authViewModel.CheckIfUserIsLoggedIn()


    }
    private fun setupNav() {
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            println(navController.currentDestination)
            when (destination.id) {
                R.id.mainMenuFragment -> {
                    showBottomNav()
                    showFab()
                }
                R.id.paperCountFragment ->{
                    showBottomNav()
                    hideFab()
                }
                R.id.profileFragment ->{
                    showBottomNav()
                    hideFab()


                }
                R.id.settingsFragment -> {
                    showBottomNav()
                    hideFab()
                }
                else ->{
                    hideBottomNav()
                    hideFab()
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    private fun showBottomNav() {
        bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        bottomAppBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    }

    private fun hideBottomNav() {
        bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
        bottomAppBar.visibility = View.GONE

    }

    private fun showFab() {
        fab.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    private fun hideFab(){
        fab.visibility = View.GONE
    }





}
```